# How can I use an implicit function with two parameters (Scala)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, implicit

I've tried this two options:

```
object DSChecker {
  implicit def checkImplFunction(dataset: Dataset[Row], config:Config): Checker = new Checker (dataset, config)
}
```

and

```
object DSChecker {
  implicit def checkImplFunction(dataset: Dataset[Row])(implicit config:Config): Checker = new Checker (dataset, config)
}
```

They compile, but the problem is when I need two use them.

I've tried also multiple combinations, but they don't compile...
(evalDifferences is a "normal" function inside clas Checker)

```
//Whithout implicit args in implicit function
import DSChecker._
(df1, difConfig).evalDifferences(df2)
```

or

```
// With config as implicit arg in implicit funciton
import DSChecker._
df1.evalDifferences(df2)
```

The problem is always the same... the compilator doesn't find "evalDifferences" method.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for an extension method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I think extension method fits better:

```scala
object DSChecker {
  implicit class DfExtension(df: Dataframe) {
    def checker(implicit config: Config) = {
      new Checker(df, config)
    }
  }
}

df1.checker.evalDifferences(df2)
```

You can also expose `evalDifferences` directly as extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Tuple`:

```
object DSChecker {
  implicit def checkImplFunction(data: (Dataset[Row], Config)): Checker = new Checker (data._1, data._2)
}
```

Then, this should work:

```
//Whithout implicit args in implicit function
import DSChecker._
(df1, difConfig).evalDifferences(df2)
```